# overflow property returning auto value

Tags: css

I've applied `html,body{width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}` to hide the overflowing html but it's causing the scrollbar seems it has been written as `overflow-x: auto;`. Why is this happening?

---

here's the screen shot:

[image]

Tested in Firefox 26.0, Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m

Comment: [live site](http://www.sabahbazaar.com/)

Comment: I am not getting a horizontal scroll bar in Chrome on OS X?

Comment: Same - i'm getting 2 vertical bars though.

Comment: So, how to solve this problem?

Comment: I couldn't understand why my question is going to be closed?

Comment: I voted to close because your problem can't be reproduced by anyone here. Try adding more information - a screenshot would be very helpful along with your browser version etc.

Comment: if you remove the overflow-x: hidden; then this will not show the two vertical scrollbar. But I need to set this because some space on the body is appearing.... thanks for concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to remove the inner-vertical scrollbar, you would use the following instead:

```
html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
body {
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

Hide the horizontal scrollbar on both the `html`/`body` elements and specify `overflow-y: hidden` on the `body` element to remove the inner-vertical scrollbar generated. This will preserve the outer horizontal scrollbar on the `html` element.

Comment: This solves the problem but if you try it in my site when you scroll to bottom it's flickering.

Comment: @C-link That's interesting, would this behavior be caused by some conflicting JS?

Comment: I think it's causing with the inner scrollbar. With my answer it's not flickering and working fine. but how about just html only?

Comment: @C-link Alright - glad you figured something out.

Comment: Can you please suggest me to use that(my answer)? I'm little bit confused about just only html!

Comment: @C-link I'm not really sure what you mean by that. What are you asking me to do?

Comment: I mean html{...} will work for all browsers?

Comment: @C-link Yea, I don't see why not. You shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.....

```
html,body{width: 100%; overflow: hidden;}
```

Update:
Use `width` on elements like div,img tags and kept them inside 100% width, body will be `width:100%` and remove the `overflow` tag from body.
Use overflow on div tags if needed.

Comment: this will hide both scrollbars.

Comment: this will affect the vertical scrolling and contents will be hidden

Comment: vertical scrolling and contents won't be hidden but vertical scrollbar will be hidden @PraveenJeganathan

Comment: If you need to see vertical scrollbar I would suggest to use width property on all elements to kept them inside 100% and remove the overflow property completely. Use it only on some div if needed, but not on BODY tag. @C-link

Answer (score 1):

I just removed body from the line `html,body{width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}` which seems working perfect.

```
html{width: 100%; overflow-x: hidden;}
```