# width and height percentage won't have affect unless the element is occupied

Tags: css

I am having trouble understanding why when i am using percentages, i have no appearance on my screen, but when i use pixels i do.

this is my code:

```
<body>
    <div class="container-content"></div>   
</body>

body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.container-content{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
}
```

if i occupy my div with some content it will not have the affect i want.
if i change the position to absolute or fixed it will have the affect i want (just a box).
if i only change instead of percentages to pixels it will also have the affect i want (just a box).

what am i getting wrong here?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases like these, both the `html`/`body` elements need a height of `100%`. In doing so, it should work.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/oczw0f4g/)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

The reason it wasn't working was because the `html` element had an initial height of `0`. Since all the children elements were using percentage based values, `100%` of `0` is also `0` - thus nothing was appearing.

Comment: You're right. But in some case only applying to body but not to html works perfect....

Comment: @C-linkNepal That's because in this case the `html` element had a height of `0` because there were no other children elements. In other cases, there are children elements which then extend the height of the `html` element, therefore making the percentage based height values to work.

Comment: You have answered me [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373211/overflow-property-returning-auto-value) but really it was working just applying to html only, why?

Comment: Still uclear. Do you mean if the OP has no percentage based values in .container-content but has percentage based values in child of that container would work if it is applied to only body?